# Select Customers where not have value in other table with join

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, database-performance

I need to select all `Customer`s from the table `Customer` where `Value` in table `Customer_Value` is not 4. 
Customers:

```
 +------------+-------+
 | Customer   | ...   |
 +------------+-------+
 | 312        | ...   |
 | 345        | ...   |
 | 678        | ...   |
 +------------+-------+
```

Customer_Value:

```
 +------------+-------+
 | Customer   | Value |
 +------------+-------+
 | 312        | 1     |
 | 312        | 2     |
 | 345        | 1     |
 | 345        | 2     |
 | 345        | 3     |
 | 678        | 1     |
 | 678        | 2     |
 | 678        | 4     |
 +------------+-------+
```

To get my result I've used the following query:

```
SELECT C.Customer FROM [Customer] C
Left join Customer_Value V ON (C.Customer = V.Customer)
WHERE C.Customer NOT IN (SELECT Customer FROM [Customer_Value] WHERE Value = '4')
GROUP BY C.Customer
```

So my question is:

Is that a fast and good query? Or are there some other better solutions to get all the Customer Ids?

Comment: Please specify database you're using in tags

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid Negative condition using Left Join and IS NULL Filter in where Condition.

```
SELECT C.Customer FROM [Customer] C
Left join Customer_Value V ON (C.Customer = V.Customer) and V.Value = '4'
WHERE V.Value is null
GROUP BY C.Customer
```

Comment: LEFT JOIN is the best solution for the negative operators and query performance gets better if you remove negative operators.

Answer (score 1):

Your method is overkill; the `JOIN` is not necessary.  I would use `not exists`:

```
select c.Customer 
from Customer c
where not exists (select 1
                  from customer_value cv
                  where c.Customer = v.Customer and
                        cv.value = 4
                 );
```

You can also use aggregation, if you assume that all customers have at least one row in `customer_value`:

```
select cv.customer
from customer_value cv
group by cv.customer
having sum(case when cv.value = 4 then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do

```
select * from customer c
join (
select distinct customer from customer_value where value!=4) v on c.customer = v.customer
```